# Calculating MOE for Net Migration

Tags: us-census

I'm trying to replicate how the ACS calculates their MOEs for Gross Migration and NetMigration from the latest 2013-2017 County-to-County Migration flow data. I followed their guidance/methodology for approximating a MOE for derived estimates for Gross Migration but got different results from what was published in their data table. Does anyone know how to calculate a MOE for Net Migration? or how the formula/methodology to replicate gross migration MOE?